# A class method inside another method?

Tags: ruby

Here is a method definition inside a `workflow` gem.

```
   def spec
      # check the singleton class first
      class << self
        return workflow_spec if workflow_spec
      end

      c = self.class
      # using a simple loop instead of class_inheritable_accessor to avoid
      # dependency on Rails' ActiveSupport
      until c.workflow_spec || !(c.include? Workflow)
        c = c.superclass
      end
      c.workflow_spec
    end
```

Is

```
      class << self
        return workflow_spec if workflow_spec
      end
```

equivalent to (a class method):

```
     class << self
       def workflow_spec
         return workflow_spec if workflow_spec
       end
     end
```

? If `workflow_spec` is a class method, then what's the purpose to define it inside a `method`? Is `workflow_spec` referred as `self.spec.workflow_spec`? Or just `self.workflow_spec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is *defined* in the example above. There is a call to *class method* `workflow_spec` and subsequent call to it, if it returned `truthy`.

Furthermore; this behaviour *described in the comment* inside the snipped you’ve posted.

The code

```
  class << self
    return workflow_spec if workflow_spec
  end
```

is [almost] an equivalent of:

```
  return self.class.workflow_spec if self.class.workflow_spec
```

The difference between the code in `workflow` and the code above is that `workflow` gem calls an [eigenclass](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/eigenclass.html), not a common class.

The exact equivalent would be:

```
eigenclass = class << self; self; end
return eigenclass.workflow_spec if eigenclass.workflow_spec
```

or (credits to @Jordan):

```
return singleton_class.workflow_spec if singleton_class.workflow_spec
```

Comment: It doesn't check for the existence of the class method. It *calls* the `workflow_spec` method on the singleton class and, if its return value is truthy, calls it again and returns the value returned by it.

Comment: I can't see how `if workflow_spec` is equivalent of `if self.class.methods.include? workflow_spec`. Wouldn't this actually *invoke* the method twice? (i.e. `return self.class.workflow_spec() if self.class.workflow.spec()`)

Comment: @Jordan, Amadan indeed, I need another cup of coffee. Shame on me, fixed.

Comment: @Amadan Replace `self.class` with `self.singleton_class` and you're exactly right.

Comment: @Jordan: Right, thanks, I was just copy-pasting blindly.

Comment: Here `self` in ` class << self` is an instance of a model which has `workflow` and `return workflow_spec if workflow_spec` returns the `workflow_spec` for the model instance  (`workflow_spec` is a singleton method?) ? thanks for all the comments.